# GMAT Orbit Designer

Tags: orbital-mechanics, gmat

I start to work with GMAT. I am looking into the API capabilites and I found several functions e.g. for the calculation of SSO Orbit Parameters, or Repeating Ground Tracks.

So apart from this, is there a mechanic implemented allowing to generate orbit parameters for specific requirements. Like the "Orbit Designer" which was presten in release version 2012 (!), where you could enter some parameters aimed for and GMAT calculated a suitable orbit.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This might belong on Astronomy or Physics SE, but there is an overlap

Comment: @fasterthanlight GMAT questions go here for sure, thus the GMAT tag.

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you'd like to achieve? Typically, the design of an orbit to meet specific characteristics is the role of an astrodynamics engineer.

Comment: I guess he asking something like Orbit Wizard from the AGI STK?

Comment: http://gmat.sourceforge.net/docs/R2020a/api/userguide/GettingStarted.html says "navigation.jar - Orbit determination components" - not sure if that might contain what you're looking for?

Comment: http://gmat.sourceforge.net/docs/R2020a/help.html says that orbit designer was disabled because "there were some features that did not meet quality expectations for this release and have been turned off in the release package. Most of these features can be turned on for analysis purposes, but they are not fully tested and should be used with caution." http://gmat.sourceforge.net/docs/R2020a/help.html#StartupFile would appear to be how to enable, but not really clear.